# My prefix is wet, my suffix is cheap

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is wet.
>   My suffix is cheap.
>   My infix can be expensive.
>   As a whole, I am happily devoured.

What am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are a

> Marshmallow

My prefix is wet.

> Marsh

My suffix is cheap.

> Low

My infix can be expensive.

> Mall (or perhaps All)

As a whole, I am happily devoured

> Marshmallows are very tasty.

Comment: Well done. Have a rot13(znefuznyybj) on me!

Answer (score 13):

You could be:

> **WATER CHESTNUTS**

*My prefix is wet.*

> **WATER** is wet (by definition!)

*My suffix is cheap.*

> **NUTS** (often peanuts) are often used as a metaphor for something costing very little (*"I got it for peanuts!"*).

*My infix can be expensive.*

> A treasure **CHEST** is a valuable thing indeed!

*As a whole, I am happily devoured.*

> **Water chestnuts** are delicious in many Asian dishes! Nyom, nyom...

Comment: Water is NOT wet, fight me!! (In the Sphinx's Lair, of course)

Comment: @North I wondered who'd be first to take that bait! ;-)

Comment: This was a great answer and nearly fits, but not the intended answer, sorry!