# Rearranged recounting stirs the pot

Tags: anagram

My friend always speaks in anagrams (he's *very* clever). He was describing a dispute that tore his family apart:

> Side sea we toast, "Winter moon!"

Shortly after that, I terminated my friendship with him. What happened?

<sub>Show ***your*** cleverness by finding a **single line** which is an anagram of the highlighted text **including punctuation and capitalization**. To constrain the solution, the word lengths are: 7, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3 (in that order).</sub>

Comment: Same number of spaces too?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yep!

Comment: Includes the punctuation?

Comment: @Northex Yes, including all punctuation (quotation marks, exclamation points, spaces, commas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weirdly, I was [actually there](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92850/60644), so I can tell you precisely what happened!

You see...

> **Someone said, "Water is not wet!"**

The fight that ensued was truly a thing to behold. I sure hope things don't kick off again now... ;-)

Comment: Don’t worry - I won’t pull my punches. After all, I’ve already disen-friend-chised you.